# Partitioning Ipod Classic 160gb

Tags: windows, partitioning, filesystems, ipod, fat32

I want to make some partitions on my ipod,but i have been unable to. This is what i tried:

- Using windows 7 disk managment didnt allow
- Diskpart command line said :"File system doesnt support shrinking"
- Tried several partitioning programs but the ipod didnt show up on the harddrive list.

Suggestions?

I saw that there were actually 2 partitions on the ipod, one for the firmware and another for the music. But I only see 1 on windows.

Of course i want to still use the ipod as a music player... so i dont want to reformat the whole drive to NTFS and then repartition... or is there a way to backup the data and then restore it to a fat32 partition like nothing happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can: http://forums.mactalk.com.au/12/49632-partitioning-ipod-classic.html

The communications in and out of the classic are encrypted which explains all the problems the Rockbox people have been having since the Nano2.

Obviously I might be wrong, but a few Google searches indicate that other people haven't been able to do it either.

Comment: Here is a (very old) post for mac users on how to partition your ipod. I dont know if its valid anymore
http://www.macgeekery.com/node/6

unfortunatly i dont own a mac and cant try it out...

Comment: This only works on iPods that are the generation of the Nanov1 or earlier. AKA anything prior to the iPod Classic. So it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

since you can use Norton Ghost Enterprise (v8 or v11) to backup and restore the iPod classic, you might be able try to restore to a different partition size (as long as the amount of data used doesn't exceed the availabe space on that partition) and then use the rest to your likings.

Comment: gonna try it and telly ou how did it go, thanx

Comment: Well it seems that none of the 3rd party programs recognizes the ipod as a disk... is this normal??

Comment: sadly, yes.  one of apple's major innovations with the iPod was taking a USB harddrive and making it *unusable as a hard drive*...

Comment: Wow... good thing i dont own anything else from apple